# what's the difference between calling method on @some and some

Tags: ruby, class, oop, methods

Why I'm getting error back when calling **eval_prog** on **e** but it works normally on **@e**

```
class Let < GeometryExpression
  def initialize(s,e1,e2)
    @s = s
    @e1 = e1
    @e2 = e2
  end

  def preprocess_prog
    Let.new(@s, @e1.preprocess_prog, @e2.preprocess_prog)
  end  

  def eval_prog env
    @e2.eval_prog([@s, @e1.eval_prog(env)] + env)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Please supply all code needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `e` is a local variable which only lives as long as the method does. `@e` is an instance variable attached to the Let object itself. See [Read This If You Want To Understand Instance Variables In Ruby](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/07/ruby-instance-variables/).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're talking about `@e1` and `@e2` in this method:

```
def eval_prog env
  @e2.eval_prog([@s, @e1.eval_prog(env)] + env)
end
```

You get an error from `e1.eval_prog(env)` because there is no `e1` local variable in that scope and no `e1` instance method. `@e1.eval_prog(env)` works because you do have an `@e1` instance variable.

If your class looked like this:

```
class Let < GeometryExpression
  attr_accessor :e1, :e2, :s
  #...
end
```

then [`attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) would give you `e1` and `e2` methods (and `e1=` and `e2=` methods too) and then you could say:

```
def eval_prog env
  e2.eval_prog([s, e1.eval_prog(env)] + env)
end
```

You might want to use [`attr_reader`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) instead so that you don't get mutator methods. Or probably just stick with the instance variables to keep the class's interface smaller.